# Renderpartial conditionally on masterpage in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, master-pages, renderpartial

Hi I have the following menus defined on my masterpage in a asp.net mvc web application

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("AdminMenu"); %>
<%Html.RenderPartial("ApproverMenu"); %>
<%Html.RenderPartial("EditorMenu"); %>
```

However I want to only display the right menu depending on the logged in users role. How do I achieve this?

I am starting to think that my strategy is incorrect so is there a better method for achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a simple example, you could do this:

```
<% 
    if (User.IsInRole("AdminRole")
        Html.RenderPartial("AdminMenu"); 
    else if (User.IsInRole("Approver")
        Html.RenderPartial("ApproverMenu"); 
    else if (User.IsInRole("Editor")
        Html.RenderPartial("EditorMenu"); 
%>
```

or perhaps your users can be in multiple roles, in which case something like this logic might be more appropriate:

```
<% 
    if (User.IsInRole("AdminRole")
        Html.RenderPartial("AdminMenu"); 
    if (User.IsInRole("Approver")
        Html.RenderPartial("ApproverMenu"); 
    if (User.IsInRole("Editor")
        Html.RenderPartial("EditorMenu"); 
%>
```

Or a more elegant approach for the latter using an extension method:

```
<% 
    Html.RenderPartialIfInRole("AdminMenu", "AdminRole"); 
    Html.RenderPartialIfInRole("ApproverMenu", "Approver"); 
    Html.RenderPartialIfInRole("EditorMenu", "Editor"); 
%>
```

with

```
public static void RenderPartialIfInRole
    (this HtmlHelper html, string control, string role)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(role)
        html.RenderPartial(control);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for something a little more elegant! But I agree this is a work around.

Comment: @Rippo yeah, I understand.  Actually, you might try an extension method.  I'll give an example.

Answer (score 2):

Extensions methods are the way to go here. More generally than @Joseph's `RenderPartialIfInRole`, you could use a `ConditionalRenderPartial` method:

```
<% 
    Html.ConditionalRenderPartial("AdminMenu", HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("AdminRole")); 
    Html.ConditionalRenderPartial("ApproverMenu", HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("ApproverRole")); 
    Html.ConditionalRenderPartial("EditorMenu", HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("EditorRole")); 
%>
```

...

```
public static void ConditionalRenderPartial
    (this HtmlHelper html, string control, bool cond)
{
    if (cond)
        html.RenderPartial(control);
}
```

Comment: Is ConditionalRenderPartial a mvc v2 method?

Comment: @Rippo no, I provide the implementation below but I forgot to rename it from `RenderPartialIfInRole`, which was confusing. Fixed now.